# Finding fraction of time doing an activity per hour using lubridate

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, lubridate

I have a dataset of start times and end times over an entire year for a certain activity. I want to break up the day into 24 intervals, each 1 hour in length, and then calculate and plot the fraction of time the person spent doing the activity per hour. I already converted the times using lubridate's mdy_hm().

Suppose these sample data in dataframe df:

```
start_time      end_time        duration
8/14/15 23:36   8/15/15 5:38    359
8/15/15 14:50   8/15/15 15:25    35
8/15/15 22:43   8/16/15 2:41    236
8/16/15 3:12    8/16/15 6:16    181
8/16/15 16:52   8/16/15 17:58    66
8/16/15 23:21   8/16/15 23:47    26
8/17/15 0:04    8/17/15 2:02    118
8/17/15 8:31    8/17/15 9:45     74
8/17/15 11:06   8/17/15 13:46   159
```

How can I find the fraction of the activity per hour over the whole year? I will then plot the result. I have tried extracting the hour with hour(), using group_by() on the time variables, and using the mean function within summarize() on duration, but I'm unsure of the logic.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The `group_by(...) %>% summarise(...)` works best when your data is in the 'tidy' format, where each row is 1 observation of the data you want to aggregate over. In your case, an observation is a minute worked within some given hour and date. We can do this be generating those minute-by-minute observations as a list column, use `tidyr::unnest()` to expand the generated data into a long data frame, then do your counting over that data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <-
    tibble(
        start_time = c("8/14/15 23:36","8/15/15 14:50","8/15/15 22:43",
                       "8/16/15 3:12","8/16/15 16:52","8/16/15 23:21",
                       "8/17/15 0:04","8/17/15 8:31","8/17/15 11:06"),
        end_time   = c("8/15/15 5:38","8/15/15 15:25","8/16/15 2:41",
                       "8/16/15 6:16","8/16/15 17:58","8/16/15 23:47",
                       "8/17/15 2:02","8/17/15 9:45","8/17/15 13:46")
    ) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(start_time, end_time), funs(mdy_hm))

worked_hours <- df %>%
    # First, make a long df with a minute per row
    group_by(start_time, end_time) %>% 
    mutate(mins = list(tibble(
        min = seq(from = start_time, to = end_time - minutes(1), by = as.difftime(minutes(1)))
    ))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    ungroup() %>% 

    # Aggregate over the long df (count number of rows, i.e. minutes per date, hour)
    select(min) %>% 
    mutate(date = date(min), hour = factor(hour(min), levels = 0:23)) %>%
    group_by(date, hour) %>%
    tally() %>%
    # Calculate proportion of hour
    mutate(prop = n / 60 * 100)

worked_hours %>%
    # Use tidyr::complete to fill in unobserved values
    complete(date, hour, fill = list(n = 0, prop = 0)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = hour, y = prop)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    facet_wrap(~ date, ncol = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this gets me closer. How could I get my two columns into a tibble easily? My dataframe actually has thousands of rows. I also would like to produce combined 1 graph, rather than 1 graph for each day.